# How to install multiple whl files in cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I know how to install `*.whl` files through cmd (the code is simply `python -m pip install *so-and-so-.whl`). But since I accidentally deleted my OS and had no backups I found myself in the predicament to reinstall all of my whl files for my work.

This comes up to around 50 files. I can do this manually which is pretty simple, but I was wondering how to do this in a single line. I can't seem to find anything that would allow me to simply type in `python -m pip install *so-and-so.whl` to find all of the whl files in the directory and install them.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using the windows 7 operating system. Through there the CMD which has python 3.6 tied as a path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Windows `cmd` you can use a for loop to do this:

```
for %x in (dir *.whl) do python -m pip install %x
```

Comment: It's just `(*.whl)`, not `(dir *.whl)` (your way will work, other than trying to run `python -m pip install dir`, which naturally fails)

Answer (score 6):

Another more universal way that works on most OS is to run this using python interpreter:

```
import glob, pip
for path in glob.glob("c:/path/to/wheel/files/*.whl"):
    pip.main(['install', path])
```

Comment: Using python interpreter is the best and cross-platform way. +1

Comment: @abccd what if one whl is dependent on another , will it fail or it will just look for the dependent whl in the same directory ?

Answer (score 4):

In linux, you could do a something like :

```
for x in `ls /home/pip-packages`; do pip install $x; done
```

this will install both .whl and tar packages.

Comment: On Linux you would just do `pip install /home/pip-packages/*`

Answer (score 2):

Pip doesn't support main from v10.0.*

```
import glob
import subprocess
for path in glob.glob("c:/path/to/wheel/files/*.whl"):
    subprocess.run(f'pip install {path}')
```

Answer (score -4):

For installing multiple packages on the command line, just pass them as a space-delimited list, e.g.:

`pip install numpy pandas`

Comment: this is not an answer to the question.