# Installing some wheels with pip (and tar's?)

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) already regarding installing a Python package with a wheel file.

However, I have been asked to install a set of packages. These are all in a folder and include several whl files, one tar file and one tar.gz file .

I am trying to figure it out how should I install these.

Something along the lines of

```
pip install --user --no-index --find-links <the folder name> <a package????>
```

It is a set of packages so I am not sure how to put that in there. Or should I just stop at `<the folder name>`?

Answer (score 1):

The following two commands will help you out:

```
//for the whl files
for %x in (path\*.whl) do python -m pip install --user --no-index --no-deps %x

//for the tar.gz file
python -m pip install --user --no-index --no-deps path\to\file
```

If you want to use a single command, you even modify the for loop to give you both whl and tar files using:

```
for %x in (path\*.whl, path\*.tar.gz) do python -m pip install --user --no-index --no-deps %x
```

Reference 1: [How to install multiple .whl files in the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844775/how-to-install-multiple-whl-files-in-the-right-order)

Reference 2: [How to install multiple whl files in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314517/how-to-install-multiple-whl-files-in-cmd)