# What port number does pycharm use when installing packages?

Tags: python, pycharm, installation, package, port-number

At my job we are not able to install packages due to strict rules in the firewall. I have pycharm installed, and need to know what port number it uses for installing and seeing available packages.

As of now when i go in to settings -> project -> Project Interpreter -> it says nothing to show.
Normally all the availible packages should be shown.

Comment: Relevant: [installing python packages without internet and using source code as .tar.gz and .whl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36725843/1324033)

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with port numbers?

Comment: what do you belive is the problem? The software is now behind a very strict firewall, that is why i belive i need to open the port in order to get the packages.