# Do I need to install Image module on Nao v1.14.5?

Tags: python-2.7, package, installation, python-imaging-library, nao-robot

I have some .py files that include " import Image " script . Do I need to install PIL? And if so how can install PIL on Nao without internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is alredy installed in 1.14.5 but you can test it easily.

```
 Connect with Putty
 type "python"
 type "import Image"
```

If the import succeeds, you dont need to install it.

Another Option is to list all installed pip packages with `pip list` [doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/)

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725843/installing-python-packages-without-internet-and-using-source-code-as-tar-gz-and) on how to install pip packages offline