# How to migrate a Django web app from local machine to another machine[with no internet; can't use PIP] as deployable app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv, web-deployment

I have a running Django application in my local system and I want to transfer and run the same to another machine in the same network. But, the destination machine cannot use PIP cmd to install dependencies as it does not have internet connectivity. Any ideas to transfer the project are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing python packages without internet and using source code as .tar.gz and .whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725843/installing-python-packages-without-internet-and-using-source-code-as-tar-gz-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system I was using is RedHat and the libs I downloaded were in CentOs and then the Django failed to start due to system dependency. Then, I tried to installing all packages in a free AWS EC2 RedHat instance and then compressed the libs together and transferred to the local machine. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install the packages in virtual environment and transfer the virtual environment folder to the another system as well.

Note: This may not work if the other system dependencies are different which are required by the app.

or simply download packages using `pip download <package_name>` and transfer the downloaded packages to other system and install there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Vitalization app like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install all requirements and dependencies on it. or you can use a portable OS like linux Ubuntu.