# Unable to install spacy 3.2.1 in windows 10 pro PC, with python 3.9.0 installed

Tags: python, spacy

I have a windows 10, 64 bit system that cannot be connected to the internet due to security reasons. I have downloaded spacy 3.2.1 with all its dependencies but while installing spacy, it shows error "this is not a supported wheel for this platform" please help me. Which version of python is required for spacy 3.2.1

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36730026/3942422

Answer (score 0):

what type or register is your machine? 32/64 bit? also is the wheel same as your register, please post both here.
If you have a 64 bit register machine, then use a 64/32 bit machine, in this case it seems you have a 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either you didn't download a Windows wheel or you are using 32bit Python, which is possible but a bad idea. (spaCy doesn't distribute 32bit Windows wheels.)

Use 64bit Python and make sure you downloaded the right wheels.