# Pip install failing due to OSError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed 100054)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pip, anaconda

System Specs:
Windows 10, Xeon processor, Latest pip version, Anaconda Environment(testenv), python 3.6
Reason for choosing python 3.6: Mediapipe.whl is only available till python3.7
[Pip install fails due to ConnectionResetError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4sJG.png)

To install the requirements of my parent project, I ran the requirements.txt on my windows 10 server. I was able to initialize a new environment with conda(python3.6). As soon as I began installing, I started getting the ConnectionResetError(10054).
This error comes irrespective of any package I try to install on my system.

Example:

(testenv) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\capture>pip install mediapipe
Collecting mediapipe
Using cached mediapipe-0.8.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (83.1 MB)
Collecting dataclasses
Using cached dataclasses-0.8-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

I also rebooted my system to make sure all available sockets close.

Then I downloaded the .whl files for my dependencies thinking I would bypass my socket error which may have been due to my Internet connection/firewall.

Still it was giving me the same output.

[Wheel file failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJqxX.png)

I tried upgrading pip, numpy, python to avoid this. But nothing helps.
Any prompt will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi Rohit welcome to Stackoverflow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814802/python-errno-10054-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-h) discussion may help you.

Comment: Hi @aps08, I do not understand why a .whl file will not get installed. Also I am working on a production system and they hardly go offline/reboot.

Comment: Maybe the `.whl` had additional dependencies that needed to be downloaded. Does this question help? [installing python packages without internet and using source code as .tar.gz and .whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725843/installing-python-packages-without-internet-and-using-source-code-as-tar-gz-and)

Comment: I had sorted the issue a while ago, it was a internet firewall issue.