# How to Install Selenium Offline?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to install Selenium in a Windows machine that does not have connection to the internet.

I have donwloaded the .whl distribution file from this link: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files and used `py -m pip install selenium.whl`command, but it still asked connection to the internet.

[image: Here's the error screenshot]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because selenium has several dependencies, one of which is `trio`. If you try to install selenium on your offline machine it will try to look for the dependencies online. This the reason for you error.

So, you have to install the dependencies as well, otherwise selenium will not work.

The way to do this is described in the following post:
[installing python packages without internet and using source code as .tar.gz and .whl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725843/installing-python-packages-without-internet-and-using-source-code-as-tar-gz-and)

Comment: Thank you, Nick. This issue has been resolved. I used "python download selenium" command, and I got the .whl of selenium and its dependencies. After installing the dependencies, I have successfully installed selenium.